# Pass props 'as' and render tag html in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass in a component props named as.

As will be bound to html tags and "link" string .

If it's a link I want it to return the Link component of react-router-dom

In the remaining cases, whatever name tag is passed, it will be rendered.

For example :

as="div" -> render <div></div>

as="span" -> render <span></span>

as="link" -> render <Link></Link>

Can you help me

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Did you try something? If so, what did you try? If not, I recommend that you try something yourself. On a side note, a variable named `as` might not work. I recommend finding a different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Component = ({ as, children }) => {
  if (as === "link") return <Link>{children}</Link>;
  const Comp = as;
  return <Comp>{children}</Comp>;
};
```

Working example:

[image: Edit stoic-poincare-58ck6l]